# Trying PHP IF Else Statements for the first time

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I'm learning PHP and trying to understand the `if .. else` statements a little better, so I'm creating a little quiz. However, I have come across an issue and I don't seem to know what the issue is. My problem is that whenever I type in the age in the input area, it will give me the `$yes` variable every time even if I enter the wrong age.

Here is my code so far:
My html file:

```
<form action="questions.php" method="post">
<p>How old is Kenny?<input></input>
<input type="submit" name="age" value="Submit"/>
</p></form>
```

My php file:

```
<?php
$age = 25;
$yes = "Awesome! Congrats!";
$no = "haha try again";

if ($age == 25){
    echo "$yes";
}else{
 echo "$no";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not say what the issue is?

Comment: Your script does not even care for what you submit. You define `$age` as 25. You compare it with 25. This will always be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You catch the user input inside the [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) superglobal var (because the method of your form is `POST`.

So

```
<?php
$age = 25;
```

should be

```
<?php
$age = $_POST['age'];
```

There is an error in HTML too. This

```
<input type="submit" name="age" value="Submit"/>
```

should be

```
<input type="text" name="age" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="Click to submit"/>
```

Because you want one input and one button. So one html element for each element.

and `<input></input>` must be cleared because it's not valid syntax :-)

Comment: I've tried this and it still gives me the wrong answer

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could edit your post and explain what the code is doing; and what you want it to do instead.

Comment: Hey, changing the input type did the job. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="questions.php" method="post">
<p>How old is Kenny?</p><input type="text" name="age"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>  


$age = (int) $_POST["age"];  
$yes = "Awesome! Congrats!";  
$no = "haha try again";  
if ($age == 25) {  
    echo $yes;  
} else {  
    echo $no;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    /* Test that the request is made via POST and that the age has been submitted too */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['age'] ) ){

        /* 
           ensure the age is an integer rather than a string .. 
           though for this not overly important
        */
        $age=intval( $_POST['age'] );

        if( $age==25 ) echo "Congratulations";
        else echo "Bad luck!";
    }
?>

<form action="questions.php" method="post">
    <p>How old is Kenny?
        <input type='text' name='age' placeholder='eg: 16' />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

A simple html form, note that the submit button does not carry the values you want to process, they are supplied via the input text element.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to echo the `variable`; echoing `"$no"` will keep it as a string. Remove the quotes from "$no" and "$yes" in your if then statement. Otherwise, your code seems sound!

Comment: No, echoing `"$no"` will echo out the value of the variable `$no`. A single-quoted string is treated as a literal; a double-quoted string will interpolate variables.

Comment: $age is getting assigned to 25, that's the issue, this code isn't sound!